# Bypass VPN from VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have a following setup:

1. Windows 7 host machine with AT&T Global Network Connection VPN
2. Virtualbox with Fedora and bridged network connection

Theoretically, as far as I know, such connection should bypass the VPN on the host machine and connect directly to the internet via WiFi connection. In practice, the VPN somehow "breaks" the underlying connection.

From experiments I have found out that modifying routes on the windows doesn't affect virtual machine in any way(which makes sense).

How can I debug what is going on and bypass the VPN so I can connect to internet directly from virtualbox?

Comment: Maybe the client is doing something weird. Are you able to use the windows integrated VPN client?

Comment: Also check: Are you still able to ping your virtual machine from another host on your network? Are you able to ping the default gateway (router)?

Comment: I provide no explanation (thus no answer), but if you only use the VPN for navigating the web, an alternative is to use a browser plugin (e.g. [zenmate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zenmate-vpn-best-cyber-se/fdcgdnkidjaadafnichfpabhfomcebme)) that only establishes the connection for that browser requests...